# What is the grammatical name and function of this sentence

Tags: syntactic-analysis

> ...which eventually develop into cacoons..

The full sentence is:

> According to researchers, the silkworm (which eventually develop into cacoons) from which raw silk is produced do well in warm climatic conditions

Comment: It's called a non-restrictive(or non-defining) relative clause, and its function is that of 'supplement'.

Comment: Perhaps the word you are looking for ***”erroneous”***, given how it’s both orthographically and biologically incorrect. Silkworms don’t develop ***INTO*** “cacoons”. The larvae metamorphosize into the chrysalides of their pupal phase, during which time they are enclosed by the silk cocoons they’ve spun to protect themselves while their pupae further metamorphosize into imagos. There is no such word as “cacoon”, and the silkworms don’t develop *INTO* cocoons; they metamorphosize *WITHIN* these outer coverings, which are no part of the organism itself, being mere wrappers of their own creation.

Comment: It's spelled _cocoon_, all O's. And as BillJ says, it's a non-restrictive relative clause (separated by parentheses instead of commas here, but pronounced the same). Its grammatical function is to modify _cocoon_, and its semantic function is to amplify the meaning of _cocoon_.

Answer (score 1):

The precise grammatical term would be that this sentence is a **relative clause** which is describing some property of your silkworms in additional detail (just as this sentence is a relative clause).